# inserting facebook app users details to database

Tags: php, mysql, facebook

i'm trying to insert user details, who authorize the app, into the database, but nothing seems to be happening. the data is null and no record is being inserted. is there something wrong with the code?

```
function insertUser($user_id,$sk,$conn)
{

    //$info = $facebook->api_client->users_getInfo($user_id, 'first_name, last_name', 'name', 'sex');
    $info = $facebook->api_client->fql_query("SELECT uid, first_name, last_name, name, sex FROM user WHERE uid = $user_id");

    for ($i=0; $i < count($info); $i++) {
    $record = $info[$i]; 
    $first_name=$record['first_name'];
    $last_name=$record['last_name'];
    $full_name=$record['name'];
    $gender=$record['sex'];

    }

    $data= mysql_query("select uid from users where uid='{$user_id}'",$conn);
    if(mysql_num_rows($data)==0)
    {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO users (uid,sessionkey, active, fname, lname, full_name, gender) VALUES('{$user_id}','{$sk}','1', '{$first_name}', '{$last_name}', '{$full_name}', '{$gender}')";
        mysql_query($sql,$conn);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Is it giving you an error ? If you dump $info what do you get ? By the way, within the "mysql_num_rows" conditional, you are returning true without checking first whether mysql_query execution was successful.

Comment: it's not giving me any error. it's just not inserting any records to the database. using var_dump this is what i get: `array(1) { [0]=> array(5) { ["uid"]=> string(10) "[profile_no*]" ["first_name"]=> string(4) "[name]" ["last_name"]=> string(6) "lastname" ["name"]=> string(11) "fullname" ["sex"]=> string(0) "" } }`   *i've edited the profile no and the name. .tho the gender isn't being retrieved. how do i check if the mysql_query execution was successful or not?

Comment: mysql_query returns TRUE or FALSE on every SQL statement that is inserting/updating info at the database - on the other hand it returns the actual resource or FALSE on error on any given select statement. Bottomline, you can do "if (mysql_query($sql) )"

Comment: k, i did that and i also tried the code on a separate project, it works, and there seems to be nothing wrong with the code in itself. but it seems the Post-Authorization Callback ping isn't working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

called the install code manually, rather than leave it upon facebook to ping the url.